# log4j for a jar won't read the configuration file

Tags: java, log4j2

I have been trying to get log4j-2.0-b9 to work with a jar but haven't been able to. I want the properties file outside the .jar and in the same directory as the .jar file but log4j doesn't seem to pick it up and defaults to printing on the console. My configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                 xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="append" value="false"/>
  <param name="file" value="C:\Users\abhishek\workspace\log4jtest\log.log"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

 <root>
  <level value="ALL"/>

  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
 </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And my JAVA code looks like:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {

private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.error("Test error");
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you starting java? What is CLASSPATH set to?

Comment: I have tried `java -jar application.jar` and `java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:"log4j.xml" application.jar`. None worked.

Comment: try ```-Dlog4j.configuration="log4j.xml"```

Comment: My manifest has Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.test.Test

Comment: Tried it. Still prints to the console.

Comment: UPDATE: There was a log4j.properties in the META-INF directory which I cano only assume was put there automatically. I removed it and it threw an error.

ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger

ERROR Test Test error

So I am assuming that its taking that log4j.properties. How do I get it to take the one outside its classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in the question uses the log4j-1.2 format.
Log4j-2.0 uses a different XML format. The configuration file should also be called `log4j2.xml` instead of `log4j.xml`. The easiest way to configure is to put the `log4j2.xml` file in the classpath.

The online docs have many example configurations: for example for [File Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender), and  the [Console](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender).

Note that you need **both** the log4j-api-2.0 and log4j-core-2.0 jar files in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

The log4j configuration file needs to be in the classpath to be seen.  If you're running java from a jar, then that jar file is your classpath, so the log4j configuration will have to be in that jar.

If you don't want to do that, perhaps you can add the "Class-Path" header to the manifest of the jar file.  I haven't tried that myself, but it's described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Comment: Tried that. Still the same error as before.

    ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation,     using SimpleLogger ERROR Test Test erro

Comment: Doesn't java -jar ignore provided classpath?  You need to do it manually: `java -cp <jar:log4jfile> <mainClass>`, and provide both the jar and the extra directory as the classpath.

Comment: Yes, I spoke too soon.  Classpath is ignored when using java -jar.